# For which $a$, the integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^a}{1-x}dx$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Find $\forall a \in R$ for which the integral:

$$
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^a}{1-x}dx
$$

Converges.

---

### My Question

Lets define $f(x)$

$$
f(x) = \frac{1-x^a}{1-x}
$$

Why cant we say that $f(x)$ is continuous in the interval except for $x = 1$.

Therefore, we can define:

$$
\forall 1 \neq 0 \in R: g(x) = f(x)
$$

And:

$$
x = 1: g(x) = 0
$$

Therefore, both integrals of $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ are the same as the functions are the same except for 1 point.

Now, bby using LHopital

$$
\lim_{x \to 1}g(x) = 1
$$

Therefore, $g(x)$ is continuous therefore integrable in the closed inteval: $[0,1]$ and we can conclude:

$$
\int_{0}^{1}g(x)dx
$$

Converges

Therefore our original integral converges.

Why not that way?

Comment: If you define $g(1)=0$ then $g$ is not continuous. Furthermore, $\lim_{x\to 1} g(x)=a$, not $1$. But you're on the right track.

Comment: This is the integral representation of the harmonic number $H_a$ and it converges for $a>-1$

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate without worrying about the end-point, as long as the function converges. You need to treat both ends of the interval, especially when $a$ is not positive.